# How many eventhub namespaces can I have?

Tags: azure, namespaces, azure-eventhub

IN https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-quotas, it said:
across all tiers, **Number of Event Hubs namespaces per subscription    -   100**

and then further down the same page, it said:
**Namespaces    50 per CU (dedicated tier)**

Which is correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100 namespaces per subscription is common to all tiers. You can ask this limit relaxed to 1000 via a support ticket.

Dedicated tier has capacity enforced limit on top of the subscription limit mentioned above. Simply put, each Dedicated Capacity Unit allows 50 namespaces. So, say with 4 CUs, you can create 200 namespaces.

Comment: so if I am on 1 subscription with 10 CUs, how many event hub namespaces can I create without raising limit with support? thanks!

Comment: 100 since subscription limit will be hit first. In that case, you can file a support ticket for an increase to 1000. Btw, 1000 is going to be default very soon.